# removing list formatting in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some spark code like this:

```
val combPrdGrp = custPrdGrp3.join(cmpgnPrdGrp3)

val combPrdGrp2 = combPrdGrp.groupByKey


val combPrdGrp3 = combPrdGrp2.map{case (k3, vals3) => {
  val valsString3 = vals3.map{case (id3, m3) => {
     s"$id3 $m3"
     }
   }
   s"$k3 $valsString3"
 }}
```

when I do a `combPrdGrp3.first` I get the below results.

```
res1: String = 110| List( {'CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG': {PRVCY_CALL: 1, PRVCY_SWP: 1, PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 4}}|  {'CARDXSL1503L': {contacted: '3/25/2015', channel: 'CARD-XSL', hit_home_date: 'ASPEN - Reminder', campaign: 'XSELL TO 360', creative: 'EM', refcode: 'Y'}})
```

I want the `List(` and its ending `)` to be removed but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I tried to use `.pipe` but that didn't seem to work like this:

```
val combPrdGrp4 = combPrdGrp3.pipe("sed s/List((//g").pipe("sed s/)//g")
```

that would crash sc for some reason. I would get a `sc shutdown` error when trying to process the results.

doing a `combPrdGrp2.first` produces this result:

```
res2: (String, Iterable[(String, String)]) = (110|,CompactBuffer(( {'CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG': {PRVCY_CALL: 1, PRVCY_SWP: 1, PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 4}}|, {'CARDXSL1503L': {contacted: '3/25/2015', channel: 'CARD-XSL', hit_home_date: 'ASPEN - Reminder', campaign: 'XSELL TO 360', creative: 'EM', refcode: 'Y'}})))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the `CompactBuffer`/`List` yourself using `mkString` :

```
List(1, 2, 3).toString
// String = List(1, 2, 3)

List(1, 2, 3).mkString
// String = 123

List(1, 2, 3).mkString(", ")
// String = 1, 2, 3
```

In case of your `combPrdGrp2` this could look like :

```
val elem = (
  "110|", 
  Iterable((
    "{'CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG': {PRVCY_CALL: 1, PRVCY_SWP: 1, PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 4}}|",
    "{'CARDXSL1503L': {contacted: '3/25/2015', channel: 'CARD-XSL', hit_home_date: 'ASPEN - Reminder', campaign: 'XSELL TO 360', creative: 'EM', refcode: 'Y'}}"
  ))
)
val combPrdGrp2 = List(elem)

combPrdGrp2.map { case (n, list) => 
  val formattedPairs = list.map { case (a, b) => s"$a $b" }
  s"$n ${formattedPairs.mkString}"
}
```

Comment: getting a `<console>:20: error: not found: value n` but I see n in the case part in `combPrdGrp2.map`....also, instead of doing `val combPrdGrp2 = combPrdGrp.groupByKey`...it become `val combPrdGrp2 = List(combPrdGrp)`? When I do combPrdGrp2.first, I get this error: `<console>:58: error: value first is not a member of List[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String))]]`...and what happens to the group by key as well?

Comment: 1) I have correct the typo in my answer, so it compiles correctly. 2) You still would use `val combPrdGrp2 = combPrdGrp.groupByKey`. `List(elem)` was just to create a collection with similar content to show how `mkString` would work in your case.